# How can I remove the shadow of a container when flipping a div?

Tags: css, html, containers, shadow

I'm trying to create a card which will come into focus on mouse rollover (ie, I increase the size and shadow so the card becomes 'more 3D') and flip over to reveal more information on mouse click.

At the moment, I have it working almost perfectly - the only problem is that I have to use a container to hold everything in perspective, and I apply the hover and focus effects to this - which means when I flip the card, its shadow remains and ruins the effect. I have a demo here to make this clear:

http://jsfiddle.net/dbPf4/14/

This is the HTML:

```
<div id=f1_container>

<input type="checkbox" id="button">
<label class="f1_card" for="button">
    <div class="front face">
      <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Cirques.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
      <p>Any content can go here.</p>
    </div>
</label>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
#f1_container:hover,#f1_container:focus{
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}  

#f1_container{
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
}

#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

input{display:none}

.f1_card {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
    display:block;
}

input:checked + .f1_card{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
} 

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Here is my attempt to achieve that: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/dbPf4/18/

Comment: thank you, this is definitely better! but when the card has been flipped the shadow only gets darker on mouse rollover, it should be darker as long as the card is in focus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your shadow to `f1_card`

It's means that your css code is:

```
#f1_container:hover,#f1_container:focus{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}  

#f1_container{
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
}

#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

input{display:none}

.f1_card {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
    display:block;
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
}

input:checked + .f1_card{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-box-shadow:-5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
} 

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#f1_container:hover .f1_card,#f1_container:focus .f1_card{
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

#f1_container:hover input:checked + .f1_card, #f1_container:focus .f1_card input:checked + .f1_card{
  -moz-box-shadow:-10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  box-shadow:-10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/dbPf4/19/

Comment: thank you, this is almost perfect! the only thing is the speed of the shadow transition - when the card comes into focus its shadow appears gradually, but if I speed this up I also end up with a really fast flip...any ideas?

Comment: Of course you can also use shades of the same size!

Answer (score 0):

What about adding some Jquery

```
$(".front.face").click(function(){
    $("#f1_container").css("box-shadow","none");
    $("#f1_container").css("-webkit-box-shadow","none");
});

$(".back.face.center").click(function(){
    $("#f1_container").css("box-shadow","5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7)");
    $("#f1_container").css("-webkit-box-shadow","5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7)");
});
```

Its not perfect but you get the idea..

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dbPf4/16/